# Regex not working to match markdown header starting with hash

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong in the following. 
i want to match markdown header # with following one space.

```
function fizz_buzz($markdown) {
    $markdown = trim($markdown);
    preg_match('/^#{1,6}\s(w+)/', $markdown, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        print_r($matches);
}
echo fizz_buzz("# header");
echo fizz_buzz("### header");
```

Its outputs empty array, should match both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `\w+` instead of `w+` to match any word character

```
function fizz_buzz($markdown) {
    $markdown = trim($markdown);
    preg_match('/^#{1,6}\s(\w+)/', $markdown, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);
}
echo fizz_buzz("# header");
echo fizz_buzz("### header");
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/OZm1h)